# Photos Not Loading in Shiny Within DT Datatable on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have an app hosted on shinyapps.io that contains a DT datatable. The data frame used in the datatable has a field that contains references to photos hosted on the web in this format - "<img src="http://pathmet.pathvudata.com/pathmet/Burlington_VT/Alderaan/ABNF7/000.png" . When I run the app in rstudio and even in a browswer the photos display fine in a DT datatable. But when I publish the app to shinyapps.io I get broken photo links. This is only a recent phenomenon; the photos on the shinyapps.io site have been working for over a year until recently. Any idea what is happening with shinyapps.io?

Comment: Are the <img>-tags correct when you look at the HTML code on shinyapps.io?

Comment: what to you mean by 'on shinapps.io'? Like inspecting the webpage in developer tools?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Those are `https` URLs, but the SSL on that server seems to be misconfigured. If you can remove the 's' to make them `http` links, it should work. Or fix the SSL configuration on the server, that would be best.